# vuejs2 get return network error

Tags: api, vuejs2, prestashop

I am trying to access a prestashop API with vuejs2

```
<script>
import axios from 'axios'

export default {
  data () {
    return {
      get: [],
      errors: []
    }
  },
  created () {
    axios({
      method: 'get',
      url: 'https://myprestashopsite.com/api/categories/?ws_key=J***************Z&filter[id_parent]=5&output_format=JSON'
    }).then(response => {
      this.get = response.data
    })
      .catch(e => {
        this.errors.push(e)
      })
  }
}
```

In the web developer console of mozilla I see that my request return a 200 with the data in the response. But I get "Error: Network Error   app.js%20line%201266%20%3E%20eval:15:15" catch as an error.

I tried with another API and it worked, so I guess it comes from the prestashop api. (prestashop version 1.7.3.0)

Is there a way to fix this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems to come from axios. I had to add a rule to the server.

I found the solution to this on this thread :

https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/853

There are other solutions I didn't try in this thread if mine doesn't work.

how to add the rule : https://enable-cors.org/server.html